# Read a part of Filename in C++

Tags: c++, file, filenames

Can we read a part of FileName in C++? For example, I have two files named howdoyoudo1.cpp and howdoyoudo2.cpp, I need a C++ code to read the FileName xxxxxxxxdo1.cpp first later xxxxxxxxdo2.cpp, even though they are shown in the dir modified based on DateTime or by name or by whatever. First when the programs executes it must read the file xxxxxxxxdo1.cpp and then xxxxxxxxdo2.cpp and so on if there are xxxxxxxxdoNth.cpp's .....

Guide me, thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't understand the question. A file may have no, one, or many filenames (at least on Posix systems)... What do you mean by "read the FileName"? And what is the operating system you are targetting??

Comment: I believe the solution is to sort the file list generated by whatever method you are getting it. You did not mention the OS or how you are retrieving the file name so we can not be specific.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the comment, to answer the first question of yours: **the file names are already defined for suppose: howdoyoudo1.cpp to howdoyoudo25.cpp, I need to read first XXXXXXXXdo1.cpp, later do2.cpp and so on up to do25.cpp**. And for OS, *Cross Platform*

Comment: @drescherjm OK, we get the file list but I need to first read the name of the file howdoyoudo1.cpp. And OS is Cross Platform. Thanks

Comment: boost filesystem is perfect for this. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: I also use and recommend Qt. However that is a big library to use if you are not using the GUI part..

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah mine is Console based app, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to enumerate all files on the target directory and in the process do the following::
2. Copy the filename into some buffer say BuffSrc.
3. Search for the string "do" in the BuffSrc.

If you want to search for num too, you have to write a for loop and save "do%d.cpp" to some buffer before searching for the string in filename buffer i.e., BuffSrc.

When do1.cpp found, increment the counter and again save the search_string to buffer till you enumerate all files on the directory.

Comment: Thanks, its clear to me, will try to implement :)